# Zlib and Base64 in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

So I am using an API which compresses its returns with ZLIB then Base64 encodes them. I have read that the Deflate stream that is included in `System.IO.Compression` uses zlib to compress and decompress. My code it below:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(csbServerNew);
    try
    {
        var result = await client.GetAsync(call);
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(resultContent);
        MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            dstream.CopyTo(output);
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

When I get to `dstream.CopyTo(output)` my code immediately throws an `System.IO.InvalidData` exception. Is there anything in my code I am doing wrong?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream` does not handle the first 2 bytes that some compression algorithms add to the front of the data. All I had to do was seek 2 bytes down the memory stream and start from there and the code worked

**Edit:**

```
...
MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
input.Seek(2, SeekOrigin.Begin);
using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    dstream.CopyTo(output);
}
string myStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(output.ToArray());
return myStr;
```

Comment: Since you've been able to figure it out, maybe you'd consider posting the code you've used to skip those initial bytes for future readers?

Comment: Will do! Updating answer now.